# Run minecraft server minimized through BAT

Tags: batch-file, jar

so recently I've made a function that launches my server when someone asks for it, but I don't want it to disrupt me while I'm playing, let's say,
Is there any way to start the server seamlessly ?
I use this BAT file to launch it through python.

> cd C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\OneDrive\Bureau\Serv\Xection
>
> java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar server.jar

Thanks in advance

EDIT : Stupid question, you just need to add "nogui" after server.jar

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using autoit scripting.here is a oneliner that will start your program hidden.Download autoit from [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/).after downloading autoit,create a file named `whatever.au3` and past the following code with your path.

```
Run("Your program path", "", @SW_HIDE)
```

just run the script and it will start the executable hidden as a process.